User exactly duplicates one of their answers to a question involving $n$ and posts it on one of its duplicates where the value of $n$ is given
If a user exactly duplicates one of their answers to a question involving a general situation (like an unknown constant $n$ and posts it on one of its duplicates that focuses on a specific case of the general situation stated above(like the value of $n$ is given, is it considered as a duplicate answer? In such a case, should I flag the latter answer for moderator intervention stating that it is a duplicate answer?

I don't recall any policy/suggestion/discussion concerning flagging duplicate answers. Duplicate questions, sure, but duplicate answers? Why?

About a month ago(when I thought it was okay to duplicate answers), I duplicated one of my answers and received a comment from a moderator requesting that I shouldn't do so. Since then, I have changed my opinions about this issue.

@GerryMyerson IMO answers explaining the same method should not be flagged unless they're exact or almost exact copies of one another and differ a few minutes. I don't see why anyone would want to essentially repost an answer ditto other than gaming for reputation.

OK, so, what are you supposed to do if your answer to one question would also be a good answer to another question? I suppose you should vote to close one of the questions as a duplicate of the other. Or just leave a comment on one question linking to your answer at the other question.

@GerryMyerson yes, when I find such a question, I flag it as a duplicate, never thought of linking my answer to that question though.

My query is that what I should do if I find someone has duplicated their answer over a duplicate of a question that should be closed.

Posting the same answer on multiple questions is not prohibited.  Don't flag.
If you notice duplicate answers, it might a warning sign.  I recommend taking a closer look at the questions to see if they are good questions, check if they might be duplicates, etc.  If someone posts a duplicate answer on two questions, often it is a sign that those questions might not be ideal -- they might be duplicates, or they might be trivial variations on a common theme (and maybe it's best to ask a more general question and close them both as a duplicate of that more general question).  Not always.  Sometimes everything is fine.

Can you please elaborate on what I should do if I encounter duplicate answers? What is it a warning sign for?

@MathGuy, I already explain that in my answer.  Regarding what you should do: "I recommend taking a closer look at the questions to see if they are good questions, check if they might be duplicates, etc."  Regarding what it is a warning sign for: "If someone posts a duplicate answer on two questions, often it is a sign that those questions might not be ideal -- ..."
